# Trapping a ConnectException in a JAX-WS webservice call

Tags: java, web-services, exception, jax-ws, webservices-client

I am using JAX-WS 2.2.5 framework for calling WebServices. I want to identify the special case when the call fails because the Web Service is down or not accessible.

In some calls, i get a WebServiceException.

```
    catch(javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException e)
    {
        if(e.getCause() instanceof IOException)
            if(e.getCause().getCause() instanceof ConnectException)
                 // Will reach here because the Web Service was down or not accessible
```

In other places, I get ClientTransportException (class derived from WebServiceException)

```
    catch(com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException ce)
    {

         if(ce.getCause() instanceof ConnectException)
              // Will reach here because the Web Service was down or not accessible
```

What's a good way to trap this error?

Should I use something like

```
    catch(javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException e)
    {
        if((e.getCause() instanceof ConnectException) || (e.getCause().getCause() instanceof ConnectException))
         {
                   // Webservice is down or inaccessible
```

or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll want to treat UnknownHostException also!

```
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();

        while (cause != null)
        {
            if (cause instanceof UnknownHostException)
            {
                //TODO some thing
                break;
            }
            else if (cause instanceof ConnectException)
            {
                //TODO some thing
                break;
            }

            cause = cause.getCause();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to identify the top level `Exception` to catch. As you have pointed out, here it's `WebServiceException`.

What you can do next it's being more generic to avoid `NullPointerException` if `getCause()` returns `null`.

```
catch(javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException e)
{
    Throwable cause = e; 
    while ((cause = cause.getCause()) != null)
    {
        if(cause instanceof ConnectException)
        {
            // Webservice is down or inaccessible
            // TODO some stuff
            break;
        }
    }
}
```